# Do Pokémon all have different max stats?

Tags: pokemon-go

Ignoring the power of individual attacks, do Pokémon at their max CP level have different stats (HP, attack, speed, etc)?

In other words, would my adorable Butterfree (stat-wise) finally have a chance to take down a max level Dragonite?

Comment: I would think so, but I'm not sure

Comment: I believe your Butterfree would still be in disadvantage. Butterfree has the base stats of 120 stamina, 144 attack and 144 defense, while Dragonite has 182, 250, 212

Comment: @dly That's true in the traditional games, but does Pokemon Go use those same base stats? A recent answer showed that even though STAB was implemented, it's not the same as the handheld series, so we can't assume mechanics carry over.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed implemted in Go. I've found similar data in the same source, where STAB was confirmed to be implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the *protobuf* file has been accepted as valid source to prove STAB I'll use the same file to prove the existence of individual stats.

**Butterfree:**

```
Pokemon {
        UniqueId: V0012_POKEMON_BUTTERFREE
        ModelScale: 1.11
        Type1: POKEMON_TYPE_BUG
        Type2: POKEMON_TYPE_FLYING
        Camera {
          DiskRadiusM: 0.999
          CylRadiusM: 0.666
          CylHeightM: 1.11
          CylGroundM: 0.555
          ShoulderModeScale: 0.5
        }
(...)
        Stats {
          BaseStamina: 120
          BaseAttack: 144
          BaseDefense: 144
        }
(...)
```

**Dragonite:**

```
Pokemon {
    UniqueId: V0149_POKEMON_DRAGONITE
    ModelScale: 0.7
    Type1: POKEMON_TYPE_DRAGON
    Type2: POKEMON_TYPE_FLYING
    Camera {
      DiskRadiusM: 0.63
      CylRadiusM: 0.42
      CylHeightM: 1.47
      CylGroundM: 0.595
      ShoulderModeScale: 0.5
    }
(...)
    Stats {
      BaseStamina: 182
      BaseAttack: 250
      BaseDefense: 212
    }
(...)
```

According to this a Dragonite is indeed stronger than Butterfree.

Comment: As disappointing as that is, that looks like proof to me.

Comment: What is this protobuf?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers ..there is a datamined Pokémon Go protobuf file on GitHub: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf